# Numerical on change in degree of dissociation wrt pressure

Tags: equilibrium

> The degree of dissociation of $\ce{PCl5}$ is 0.4 at 2 atm pressure and T kelvin. At what pressure will degree of dissociation of $\ce{PCl5}$ be 0.6?

Taking the degree of dissociation as 0.4, I got the partial pressure of $\ce{PCl5}$ to be $\frac{2}{2.33}$. I then thought of taking the degree of dissociation as 0.6 and multiplying the mole fraction of $\ce{PCl5}$ with the total unknown pressure and equating it to the partial pressure of $\ce{PCl5}$. But I then realized that wouldn't the partial pressure change with change in total pressure?
I'm not able to figure this question out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dissociation of $\ce{PCl5}$ is given by the equation:

$$\ce{PCl5(g) <=> PCl3(g) + Cl2(g)}$$

with $\displaystyle K_\text{p} = \frac{p_{\ce{Cl2}}p_{\ce{PCl3}}}{p_{\ce{PCl5}}}$. Putting this in terms of total pressure, $\displaystyle K_\text{p} = \frac{x_{\ce{Cl2}}x_{\ce{PCl3}}}{x_{\ce{PCl5}}}p_\text{T}$.

In terms of the degree of dissociation, $\alpha$, assuming an initial amount $y$ of moles of $\ce{PCl5}$, at equilibrium, we have $n_{\ce{PCl5}} = y - \alpha y\,\text{mol}$, $n_{\ce{PCl3}} = \alpha y\,\text{mol}$, and $n_{\ce{Cl2}} =  \alpha y\,\text{mol}$. Thus, their molar fractions are $x_{\ce{PCl5}} = \frac{1 - \alpha}{1 + \alpha}$, $x_{\ce{PCl3}} = \frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha}$, and $x_{\ce{Cl2}} =  \frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha}$, so:

$$K_\text{p} = \frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right)}p_\text{T} = \frac{\alpha^2}{1-\alpha^2}p_\text{T}$$

Since at $p_\text{T} = \pu{2 atm}$, $\alpha = 0.4$, we get $K_\text{p} = \pu{0.381 atm}$. Hence, for $\alpha = 0.6$, since $K_\text{p}$ doesn't change (i.e. assuming it's an isothermic system), we get $p_\text{T} = \pu{0.677 atm}$. This is in agreement with Le Chatelier's principle: reducing the total pressure will push the equilibrium towards the side with more gaseous moles, so the dissociation constant in this case will be higher.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was confused why Kp would remain same but then realised since Kp=Kc(RT) ^deltaN, since Kc and T are constant and R and delta N are fixed values, Kp must remain the same. Thanks for the help!